Real time streaming from snowflake to Azure Databricks
Snowflake having some tables which needs to stream into databricks.I have explored autoloader but i think it doesnot support snowflake as source. Can you please guide ?

Did you tried any other way and facing blockers?  If yes please add those blockers

No, got to know snowflake also doesnot support spark structured streaming.So, right now no real time streaming method i got.
